# Want to know which Jenkins job is executing now, in java

Tags: java, jenkins

I have 3 Jenkins job. Below are the name of those Jenkins job:

1. test_existing_api
2. test_others_api
3. test_new_api

I have a config file in java project which have 3 different configuration. I want to pick the configuration depend upon Jenkins job. So first I want to check which Jenkins job is executing and then I will take configuration according to that job. That configuration will further require in java code.

Please help me to understand how can I check which Jenkins job is executing now in Java.

Comment: you mean you want to check from within the job that is executing, or from some other software outside Jenkins?

Comment: I want to check within the job..

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to get this data within the job that is executing, see [manual entry](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables):

> **Jenkins Set Environment Variables**
>
> When a Jenkins job executes, it sets some environment variables that you may use in your shell script, batch command, Ant script or
> Maven POM 1. The following table contains a list of all of these
> environment variables.

```
Environment Variable    Description
BUILD_NUMBER    The current build number, such as "153"
BUILD_ID    The current build id, such as "2005-08-22_23-59-59" (YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss)
BUILD_URL   The URL where the results of this build can be found (e.g. http://buildserver/jenkins/job/MyJobName/666/)
NODE_NAME   The name of the node the current build is running on. Equals 'master' for master node.
JOB_NAME    Name of the project of this build. This is the name you gave your job when you first set it up. It's the third column of the Jenkins Dashboard main page.
BUILD_TAG   String of jenkins-${JOB_NAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER}. Convenient to put into a resource file, a jar file, etc for easier identification.
JENKINS_URL     Set to the URL of the Jenkins master that's running the build. This value is used by Jenkins CLI for example
EXECUTOR_NUMBER     The unique number that identifies the current executor (among executors of the same machine) that's carrying out this build. This is the number you see in the "build executor status", except that the number starts from 0, not 1.
JAVA_HOME   If your job is configured to use a specific JDK, this variable is set to the JAVA_HOME of the specified JDK. When this variable is set, PATH is also updated to have $JAVA_HOME/bin.
WORKSPACE   The absolute path of the workspace.
SVN_REVISION    For Subversion-based projects, this variable contains the revision number of the module. If you have more than one module specified, this won't be set.
CVS_BRANCH  For CVS-based projects, this variable contains the branch of the module. If CVS is configured to check out the trunk, this environment variable will not be set.
GIT_COMMIT  For Git-based projects, this variable contains the Git hash of the commit checked out for the build (like ce9a3c1404e8c91be604088670e93434c4253f03) (all the GIT_* variables require git plugin)    
GIT_URL     For Git-based projects, this variable contains the Git url (like git@github.com:user/repo.git or https://github.com/user/repo.git)\\
GIT_BRANCH  For Git-based projects, this variable contains the Git branch that was checked out for the build (normally origin/master)
```

Sorry about bad formatting (SO doesn't support nice tables), but you should be able to retrieve these variables with [System.getEnv()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv--). This means you don't need to add anything to your Jenkins configuration, just read from java what it already sets.

Answer (score 1):

> `http://<Jenkins_server>/job/<Job_name>/lastBuild/api/xml?depth=1`

Above url will give you the xml structured data, in which you can check `<building>false</building>` tag value from your java code by parsing the xml.

If value is `true` than jenkins job is running at the time.

To check which of given three job is running, you can check the status of each job by [parsing xml in java code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) for each job and get configuration file of running job.

P.S. : Replace the place holders in url with applicable data. `<Jenkins_server>` and `<Job_name>`

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a system property from the job to the JVM when launching the project:

```
...whatever... -Dconfig=test_existing_api
```

and retrieve it in your classes with:

```
System.getProperty("config")
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I should pass system property(from Jenkins job) in Build --> Execute shell or from some where else

Comment: It depends on how you launch your java application. If you execute a shell script then yes, if it's a maven job then add it on the `Goals and options` line, etc

Comment: I execute shell script and I update Execute Shell as below   1)pushd src
2)chmod +x ./setenv.sh
3)source ./setenv.sh
4)ant cleanall
5)ant compile
6)-Dconfig=test_existing_api
7)ant runAllTests   and getting below exception 
 + -Dconfig=test_existing_api
/tmp/hudson5074006777121298600.sh: line 7: -Dconfig=test_existing_api: command not found

Comment: At this point your question became unclear. If you need that system parameter to reach the tests, you may need to pass the property from jenkins to ant [6)ant Dconfig=test_existing_api runAllTests], and then from ant to the junit tests [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451045/passing-java-system-properties-to-ant-tests] where you can access with `System.getProperty("config")`. It would be helpful if you could update the question with a complete description of your jenkins job also including where you need to make that decision in your java clases